# Call a python script in a python script

Tags: python, call, subprocess

I am trying to call a python script in another python script. The directories are different. I tried

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("C:\temp\hello2.py", shell=True)
```

But got nothing. It does not work. I reviewed many forums, but all of them are about calling it when both scripts are on the same directory.

I tried having both scripts in the same directory. In this case, I can run the model in the Python.exe (through cmd window) but not in IDLE. In IDLE, I do not even get an error message.

I really need to do that, such that I can't define the other script as a different module, etc. I need to call a script in another script.

Comment: First of all use a raw string.

Comment: "got nothing"? Not even an error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape backslash (`\`)

```
"C:\\temp\\hello2.py"
```

or use raw string

```
r"C:\temp\hello2.py"
```

---

```
>>> print "C:\temp\hello2.py"
C:      emp\hello2.py
>>> print "C:\\temp\\hello2.py"
C:\temp\hello2.py
>>> print r"C:\temp\hello2.py"
C:\temp\hello2.py
```

Answer (score 2):

First the backslash thing, and second you should **always** call python scripts with the python interpreter. You never know what are `*.py` files associated with. So:

```
import sys
import subprocess
subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\\temp\\hello2.py'], shell=True)
```

Comment: Although sometimes appropriate, this is not true if you want to call 3rd party python modules that expect a different python version. The system registered python is not necessarily a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'I can't define the other script as a different module, etc. I need to call a script in another script.', but I think you can avoid the whole subprocess business by just importing your other python script, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/1460057).

i.e.

```
import imp

hello2 = imp.load_source("hello2", 'C:\temp\hello2.py')
```

That should run your hello2.py script - sorry if I'm misunderstanding the constraints of your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can go for an approach by altering the sys.path list.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\temp\\")
import hello2
```